# People are possessed by heroes or demons, gaining supernatural powers

Tags: story-identification

- The possessed have super/supernatural powers of varying sorts.
- The story is told in the first-person, by the only person to have been so
  possessed and lived (I believe he was possessed as a child)
- The possessed all seem to have ‘famous’ names of superheroes (e.g. “Batman”)
  or infamous villains/killers (e.g. “Jack the Ripper”, “The Carver”).
- There's a couple of twists where we find out that the protagonist may
  still be under possession and also where he discovers that all
  possessions had something to do with someone locked in an insane
  asylum.
- I'm pretty sure it was written within past 10 years. For some reason
  thought it was written by Dan Wells of *I Am Not A Serial Killer*
  fame, but that doesn’t seem to be the case.

Comment: Can you remember anything else and year perhaps?

Comment: Spoilers should actually be hidden by the >! combination. >!text goes here

Comment: What exactly is a "media name"?  Do you just mean a name of the form "The [Noun]"?

Comment: I believe what is meant is a name that would be used/given by the media, such as Jack "The Ripper", The Boston Strangler, The Gray Man (Albert Fish), etc. Sensationalist and enticing.

Comment: The edit helped but the question is still way too vague. Why don't you try to trim it down to just the relevant bits.

Comment: I've given it a pretty radical haircut to make it clearer what you're asking and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

Figured it (randomly saw and recognized the author's name on Goodreads). The book is [Pandemonium](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3191189-pandemonium), by Daryl Gregory.

> *"It is a world like our own in every respect . . . save one. In the 1950s, random acts of possession begin to occur. Ordinary men, women,
>   and children are the targets of entities that seem to spring from the
>   depths of the collective unconscious, **pop-cultural avatars some call
>   demons.** There’s the Truth, implacable avenger of falsehood. The
>   Captain, brave and self-sacrificing soldier. The Little Angel, whose
>   kiss brings death, whether desired or not. And a string of others,
>   ranging from the bizarre to the benign to the horrific."*

It turns out I bought it on my kindle 4 or so years ago - time for a reread!